# How to select similar items using an intermediate table?

Tags: mysql, select

Following some advices, I divided a table in 3 parts, to use many-to-many queries, so now I have:

Table animes:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| id             | title       |
+----------------+-------------+
| 1              | Anime A     |
| 2              | Anime B     |
| 3              | Anime C     |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Tabela de genres:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| id             | genre       |
+----------------+-------------+
| 1              | Action      |
| 2              | Romance     |
| 3              | Ninja       |
+----------------+-------------+
```

And then a third table to intermediate animes and genres:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| anime_id       | genre_id   |
+----------------+-------------+
| 1              | 1           |
| 1              | 3           |
| 2              | 2           |
| 2              | 3           |
| 3              | 2           |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Given an anime ID, it's possible to get it genres like this:

```
SELECT an.id, an.title, GROUP_CONCAT(g.genre) AS genres
    FROM animes an 

    INNER JOIN intermediate_table ti ON ti.anime_id = an.id

    INNER JOIN genres g ON g.id = ti.genre_id

WHERE an.id = 1
```

Well, what about if I want to get a list of similar animes based on the number of common genres, what query should I do? Like I want to know all animes similar to the anime 1, and order them by the number of common genres.

[Fidddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f2569)

Comment: What is your desire output for `id = 1` ?

Comment: Well on that case, would be just the anime 2, that has only one genre similar to the 1

Comment: Your fiddile doesnt match this example. anime1 has 1,2 not 1,3

Comment: I just fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. look for the genre_id of the anime you want to find similarities.
2. check what anime have match with those genre_id
3. count them and sort them

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/383cbf/8)**

```
SELECT anime_id , COUNT(F.genre_id)
FROM anime_genre A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `genre_id`
            FROM `anime_genre`
            WHERE `anime_id` = 1 ) F
       ON A.`genre_id` = F.`genre_id`   
WHERE  `anime_id` <> 1    
GROUP BY anime_id 
HAVING COUNT(F.genre_id) > 0
ORDER BY COUNT(F.genre_id) DESC
```

**OUTPUT**

I add one additional anime to show the order of how similar they are

```
| anime_id | COUNT(F.genre_id) |
|----------|-------------------|
|        4 |                 2 |
|        2 |                 1 |
```

Comment: You put `WHERE anime_id = 1` inside of the LEFT JOIN, but what if I'm calling this id from another table, how could I pass to the WHERE clause? Just an extra question, but your answer is already more than enough to me, thank you :)

Comment: Sorry I dont understand the question. in this case I use `'1'` but you could use a variable `@anime_id` or the result of a query. `WHERE anime_id = (SELECT id FROM ....)`